# Is it possible to insert import statements with jedi-vim?

Tags: python, vim, jedi-vim

I've just started looking at the Vim jedi plugin, and it seems pretty impressive. One feature of some of the Java IDEs I've used is the ability to automatically add required imports. Can Jedi do that? For example, if I enter a line such as

```
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
```

and then invoke some Jedi command, is it possible for the plugin to automatically insert an `import sys` line at the top of the source file (if sys is not already being imported)?

I've looked through the Jedi help, and can't see anything like this - but it's possible I missed something. Alternatively, is there another Vim plugin that would do this? (It needs a certain level of understanding of Python syntax to get it right, which is why I looked to Jedi to be able to do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Jedi doesn't do refactoringing. This includes import additions. There's an issue for the whole subject: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/667.

It's not that easy to implement this command with good performance. However any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

FIY, I've defined a generic import feature that can be used on demand in [lh-dev](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev). I use it from my C&C++ suite, and from my [snippet engine (mu-template)](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/).

So far I don't parse anything to add the missing import/include statements. This part would be complex as Dave said. Instead my snippets know which files need to be imported/included and import/include them if not already imported/included.

It's far from being perfect, but it's a start. mu-template provides a hook to do stuff at the start of the file after the snippet has been expanded, this is where I call lh-dev function. If other snippet engines provide similar hooks, you should be able to call [`lh#dev#import#add()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev/blob/master/autoload/lh/dev/import.vim#L65) from your snippets.

Here a proof of concept snippet for Python (I seldom program in Python, and don't have many snippets for it): https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/python/path-exists.template